# Capitalizing the first letter of characters in a column using substr function

Tags: r, substr

I have this data frame

```
head(df)
##   patnum hospstay    lowph pltct  race  bwt gest        inout twn lol magsulf
## 1      1       34       NA   100 white 1250   35 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 2      2        9 7.250000   244 white 1370   32 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 3      3       -2 7.059998   114 black  620   23 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 4      4       40 7.250000   182 black 1480   32 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 5      5        2 6.969997    54 black  925   28 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 6      6       62 7.189999    NA white  940   28 born at duke   0  NA      NA
##   meth toc  delivery apg1 vent pneumo pda cld    sex dead
## 1    0   0 abdominal    8    0      0   0   0 female    0
## 2    1   0 abdominal    7    0      0   0   0 female    0
## 3    0   1   vaginal    1    1      0   0  NA female    1
## 4    1   0   vaginal    8    0      0   0   0   male    0
## 5    0   0 abdominal    5    1      1   0   0 female    1
## 6    1   0 abdominal    8    1      0   0   0 female    0
```

The race variable has 4 entries, "white", "black", "native american", "oriental". I am wanting to replace this string with capitalized versions "White", "Black", "Native American", "Oriental". I would like to do this using the substr function. I'm not sure what code to use to accomplish this. I was provided an example below, where the

```
day_full = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

substr(day_full_1, nchar(day_full_1)-2, nchar(day_full_1)) = "DAY"

The result is: "SunDAY", "MonDAY", "TuesDAY", "WednesDAY", "ThursDAY", "FriDAY", "SaturDAY", "SunDAY"
```

This is similar to what I want to do, but I only want to have the first letter of each of the races to be capitalized. How would I translate this to make each first letter of the 4 races capital?

This is the solution I've tried now.

```
substr(SB_xlsx$race, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(SB_xlsx$race, 1, 1))

substr(SB_xlsx$race, 1, 1) 

## structure(list(patnum = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
## 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), hospstay = c(34, 
## 9, -2, 40, 2, 62, 32, NA, NA, 28, 38, NA, 62, 69, 1, 93, 44, 
## 50, 66, 65, 44, 70, 85, NA), lowph = c(NA, 7.25, 7.059998, 7.25, 
## 6.969997, 7.189999, 7.32, NA, NA, 7.16, 7.039997, NA, 7.179996, 
## 7.419998, 7.119999, 7.239998, 7.129997, 7.269997, 7.179996, 7.07, 
## 7.289997, 7.129997, 7.189999, NA), pltct = c(100, 244, 114, 182, 
## 54, NA, 282, NA, NA, 153, 229, NA, 182, 361, 378, 255, 186, NA, 
## 260, 183, 134, 229, 68, NA), race = c("white", "white", "black", 
## "black", "black", "white", "black", NA, NA, "black", "white", 
## NA, "black", "white", "white", "black", "white", "black", "black", 
## "white", "white", "black", "white", NA), bwt = c(1250, 1370, 
## 620, 1480, 925, 940, 1255, 600, 700, 1350, 1310, 550, 1110, 1180, 
## 970, 770, 1490, 1170, 1360, 1330, 1000, 1120, 740, NA), gest = c(35, 
## 32, 23, 32, 28, 28, 29.5, 26, 24, 34, 32, 24, 28, 28, 28, 26, 
## 33, 31, 31, 31, 28, 29, 26, NA), inout = c("born at duke", "born at duke", 
## "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", 
## "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", 
## "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", 
## "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", 
## "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", "born at duke", 
## "born at duke", NA), twn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 
## 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), lol = c(NA, NA, 
## NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
## NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), magsulf = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
## NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
## NA, NA), meth = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
## 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, NA), toc = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
## NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA), delivery = c("abdominal", 
## "abdominal", "vaginal", "vaginal", "abdominal", "abdominal", 
## "vaginal", NA, NA, "abdominal", "vaginal", NA, "vaginal", "abdominal", 
## "vaginal", "vaginal", "abdominal", "vaginal", "vaginal", "vaginal", 
## "vaginal", "vaginal", "abdominal", NA), apg1 = c(8, 7, 1, 8, 
## 5, 8, 9, NA, NA, 4, 6, NA, 6, 6, 2, 4, 8, 7, 1, 8, 5, 9, 9, NA
## ), vent = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
## 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, NA), pneumo = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 
## NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA), pda = c(0, 
## 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
## 0, 0, NA), cld = c(0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, 
## 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA), sex = c("female", "female", 
## "female", "male", "female", "female", "female", NA, NA, "female", 
## "male", NA, "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "female", 
## "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", NA), dead = c(0, 
## 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
## 0, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: `tools::toTitleCase` works better than a substring check, just do `tools::toTitleCase(df$race)`.

Comment: Hi, @r2evans for our learning, is there a base R or indeed any methods which scales (with large data)?

Comment: The `tools` package is base R. So are `gregexpr`/`regmatches`. And I suspect that both of the methods in my answer will work more robustly than trying to use `substr` on strings that contain spaces. (If all you wanted was to change the first character only, then that's just `substr(vec, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(vec, 1, 1))`.

Comment: When I run the substr solution, I alter to code to fit my dataset, but the solution only produces the capital letters, not the actual word. The requirements of the project force me to use the substr as my solution unfortunately. I have updated my question to reflect.

Comment: @r2evans's solution aims to take the 1st letter of each word, upper case them then store back into 1st letter of each word. It worked for me. Try `substr(df$race, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(df$race, 1, 1))` on his df in his answer. Could you provide your reproducible dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure how to insert a reproducible data frame. I've included my original one in my question. I've updated to reflect my result

Comment: Try `dput(df)` where `df` is your dataframe. Then paste R’s output here

Comment: There we go, I added in a portion of the data frame just for reduce the size.

Comment: @Charles6445, I'm really confused: why *must* you use `substr`? You want a base-R solution, and all of the methods suggested so far are basic R, no extra package installation required. I think I demonstrated why `substr` alone is going to be problematic (i.e., upcasing the letter after a space). If you really want to use something that isn't cut out for it, I can suggest `strsplit` options that don't even require the `tools` package, but will be horribly slow.

Comment: The only reason I am using the substr function is due to my project requiring it. I've found easier/faster solutions, but the project requires that command to be used. I emailed my professor about the issues I am having, but was told "it's a part of the learning process". I may tweak my code just a bit to see what I can figure out.

Comment: You're working with 1M rows of data for a class project, and the professor wants you to use `substr` to title-case the race? Wow. You really should have *led* with *"this is a class assignment and I **must use `substr`**"* to preempt all of these questions to you.

Comment: Can you at least use `substring`, a near-synonym for `substr`? At least it's vectorized.

Comment: In hindsight, yeah that would've been a good idea. I'm also able to use paste for my data set so I may give that a shot as well.

Comment: Yes, I believe substring is also acceptable for the project, as well as paste

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions:

```r
df <- structure(list(patnum = 1:6, hospstay = c(34L, 9L, -2L, 40L, 2L, 62L), lowph = c(NA, 7.25, 7.059998, 7.25, 6.969997, 7.189999), pltct = c(100L, 244L, 114L, 182L, 54L, NA), race = c("white", "white", "black", "black", "black", "white"), bwt = c(1250L, 1370L, 620L, 1480L, 925L, 940L), gest = c(35L, 32L, 23L, 32L, 28L, 28L), inout = c("born_at_duke", "born_at_duke", "born_at_duke", "born_at_duke", "born_at_duke", "born_at_duke"), twn = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), lol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), magsulf = c(NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

tools::toTitleCase(df$race)
# [1] "White" "White" "Black" "Black" "Black" "White"
```

But those are simpler with no spaces, let's create one for this exercise:

```r
vec <- c("white", "black", "native american")
tools::toTitleCase(vec)
# [1] "White"           "Black"           "Native American"
```

We can also use `gregexpr`/`regmatches` to do it:

```r
gre <- gregexpr("(?<=^| ).", vec, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(vec, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "w"
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# [[3]]
# [1] "n" "a"
regmatches(vec, gre) <- lapply(regmatches(vec, gre), toupper)
vec
# [1] "White"           "Black"           "Native American"
```

I'm sure there's a `stringr`-variant out there as well.

As for `substr`, it's feasible to use regex to find all (1) first-chars and (2) all chars that follow a space, then extract each one, then `toupper`-them, then put that back into place ... but at that point you're still using regex and effectively doing what `toTitleCase` is doing natively and what this `gregexpr`/`regmatches` code is doing a little more verbosely.

If all you wanted to do was replace the first character, though, and not care about letters after spaces, then

```r
substr(vec, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(vec, 1, 1))
vec
# [1] "White"           "Black"           "Native american"
```

though in this case, I think the lower-case `"a"` in `"Native american"` is wrong, so I don't think this is the best approach.

---

### Scaling

Since you are concerned about scaling (I'm assuming you're venturing into 100K or more, since less than that is not going to be an issue with any method demonstrated), here's a comparison:

```r
bench::mark(
  toTitleCase = tools::toTitleCase(vec),
  gregexpr = {
    gre <- gregexpr("(?<=^| ).", vec, perl=TRUE)
    regmatches(vec, gre) <- lapply(regmatches(vec, gre), toupper)
    vec
  }
)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory             time     gc      
#   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>             <list>   <list>  
# 1 toTitleCase    401us    474us     1735.    4.15KB     0      868     0      500ms <chr [3]> <Rprofmem [9 x 3]> <bench_~ <tibble~
# 2 gregexpr       111us    205us     5240.   24.28KB     2.26  2315     1      442ms <chr [3]> <Rprofmem [6 x 3]> <bench_~ <tibble~
```

Granted, `vec` size 3 is pretty small, let's scale that up a bit.

```r
vec30000 <- rep(vec, 10000) # 30000 length
bench::mark(
  toTitleCase = tools::toTitleCase(vec30000),
  gregexpr = {
    gre <- gregexpr("(?<=^| ).", vec30000, perl=TRUE)
    regmatches(vec30000, gre) <- lapply(regmatches(vec30000, gre), toupper)
    vec30000
  }
)
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result         memory       time      gc      
#   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>         <list>       <list>    <list>  
# 1 toTitleCase    6.01s    6.01s     0.166      36MB    0.832     1     5      6.01s <chr [30,000]> <Rprofmem [~ <bench_t~ <tibble~
# 2 gregexpr    773.13ms 773.13ms     1.29      241MB    2.59      1     2   773.13ms <chr [30,000]> <Rprofmem [~ <bench_t~ <tibble~
```

Looking at the `` `itr/sec` `` column showing iterations per second, it appears that even at scale, the `gregexpr` method works better. (If you look at the source code for `toTitleCase`, you'll see why: it's consider a lot more than just space-delimited words, it's also consider linking words, exception-words, etc.)

Comment: was not expecting such a detailed answer (and the always interesting benchmarking). Read through it all. Yes, speed is v important to me as often times data come in 100ks or millions.

I don't mind the verbose methods as they also allow more flexibility. 

The combination of use of `gregexpr` & `regmatches` is new to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use perl substitution:

```
gsub('\\b(\\w)', '\\U\\1', vec, perl = TRUE)
[1] "White"           "Black"           "Native American"
```

This method is way faster (ie 35+ times Faster) than the `gregexpr` method mentioned before:

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
     gsub = gsub('\\b(\\w)', '\\U\\1', vec30000, perl = TRUE),
     gregexpr = {
         gre <- gregexpr("(?<=^| ).", vec30000, perl=TRUE)
         regmatches(vec30000, gre) <- lapply(regmatches(vec30000, gre), toupper)
         vec30000 },
     unit = 'relative', check = 'equal')

Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
     gsub  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000     5
 gregexpr 37.37549 41.10014 29.00345 24.49221 25.39978 25.54325     5
```

Comment: Yeah, perl-regex is still a bit of an opaque box to me ... this is a nice trick!